# A tree without long branches for successor cardinals

Tags: set-theory

I've been working on problems from various exams in set theory. I'm having trouble proving this assertion:

For every infinite $\kappa$ there is a tree $T$ of height $\kappa^+$ without branches of length $\kappa^+$ which satisfies $\forall x\in T\ \ \forall \beta\ (H(x)<\beta<H(T))\implies\exists y\in T_{\beta}: x<y$

I have no idea how or where to start. Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: For $\alpha<\kappa^+$ let

$$S_\alpha=\left\{\sigma\in{^\alpha\kappa}:\sigma\text{ is injective and }\big|\kappa\setminus\sigma[\alpha]\big|=\kappa\right\}\;.$$

Let $T=\bigcup_{\alpha<\kappa^+}S_\alpha$, ordered by $\subseteq$ (i.e., by end extension, if you prefer to think of it that way).

Comment: Ha! So simple. But isn't that... too simple? I mean, I see this works yet why does the question ask about successor cardinals explicitly? Couldn't we make the same construction for any $\kappa$?

Comment: @Jules: Yes, so far as I can see. Is it conceivable that the problem was misstated on the exam, and that something more complicated was actually intended?

Comment: @Jules: Is it possible that what’s wanted is a tree in which each element has successors arbitrarily high in the tree? That would require a bit more work.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, that's right! Sorry for misstating the question. I'm going to change it in a second.

Comment: @Jules: I’ve completely revised my answer; it took a while to come up with something, but I think that this works.

Comment: So... there is no branch of length $\kappa^+$ here because if there was, then the extension of elements of that branch would be an injection from $\kappa^+$ to $\kappa$?

Comment: This is brilliant but I'm not sure why every element has a successor arbitrarily high in the tree?

Comment: @Jules: That's what the requirement that $\big|\kappa\setminus\sigma[\alpha]\big|=\kappa$ is for: It lets you extend $\sigma$ arbitrarily high in the tree.